# How to securely store API_ACCESS_TOKEN in android?

Tags: java, android, rest, proguard

I have stored my API_TOKEN IN constants file and used proguard.If someone will decompile the apk he can see the API_TOKEN TO access REST API's 
so, how can in secure it and what is the best way to store the APITOKENS;

Here is my code

```
 restAdapter.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=" + 
   ConfigurationFile.API_TOKEN);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't store it in the app.  Download it from your server, and store it in the keystore, or encrypted with the key in the keystore.  Of course either way can still be worked around if someone is willing to put in enough effort.

If you're really scared, don't use it at all.  Have your server make all the requests, and send your requests through your server.  That can cost a lot of bandwidth though.

Comment: To download token from server, I have to define the REST API URL in my app constants so the third party can see it by decompiling the APK

Comment: @ShailendraSachan That's why you require user authentication to access that API-  a password known by the user in order to log into it.  If you don't have that, then yes downloading it from the server is useless and there is no way to do more than put a speedbump in the way of someone finding your token.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the token from `BuildConfig` file. Create a file called `my_file.properties` in the project's root. Keep the token there and then define an instance of that file in build (app). Under build types, create a new build config field using that value from that file instance.

So ultimately, your token value will be fetched from the `my_file.properties` file that you created.

For more, refer [Gradle tips](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html)

Comment: I did this code, but still when I decompiled my apk , the third party can see the token

Comment: Who is the 3rd party ?

Comment: you'll be storing the properties file under .gitignore

Comment: @Debdeep That doesn't actually help-  the value is still in the compiled APK.  Otherwise the APK wouldn't know it to use it.

Comment: Why don't you use proguard and obfuscate your code?

Comment: @GabeSechan I used a Jadx decompiler to inspect a similar build which was obfuscated using proguard but I couldn't find the .properties file that was placed in the project's root.

Comment: @Debdeep you aren't looking very hard, and aren't a practiced reverse engineer. The data is in there, or your app couldn't use it. Proguard will make it harder to find, but it's a just a speed bump.

Comment: You're right, I haven't really reverse engineered the app. If that's the case, then only storing the token securely would be on a server that you mentioned.